# .DWG format File Viewer in xamarin forms/ Xamarin.android/ Xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, dwg, xamarin.droid

I need to integrate *.dwg format file  in Xamarin forms/ Xamarin.android/ Xamarin.ios
how can I able to show **DWG** AutoCAD file in Android and iOS.
dwg file contains floor plan which I need to select space.

if any nuget package available for Xamarin?

any kind of if anyone has any idea let me know.

Floor Plan DWG File sample-
http://www.cadforum.cz/catalog_en/file.asp?blk=12286

[image]

Comment: AutoCad keep the dwg file formats private, hence its hard to impossible to get a good reader for them, besides AutoCad. I did reverse engineer a little of it many years ago but no where near being able to display it. As Allister recommends, convert it to SVG and display that. You have almost no hope in viewing a dwg file directly in Xamarin. Another option is opening it in the AutoCAD app, if you don't mind the user leaving your app.

Answer (score 0):

if you can save them as SVGs there are a few SVG nugets for xamarin.
https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading has support I believe though I haven't tried it,
https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/SVG is what we use for all the icons in our xamarin.forms app so we don't need all the different png sizes for droid and ios.